# How to convert values of a pandas data frame column to a numeric representation based on the number of unique values, all at once in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to convert values of a pandas data frame column to numeric representation based on the number of unique values all at once? for example 
Original DF

```
data= {'Col1': ['G1', 'G2', 'G9','G4','G6',''],
     'Col2': ['H2', 'H1', 'H9','H9','',''],
     'Col3': ['D2', 'D1', 'D9','','',''],
     'Col4': ['GHD2', 'GHD1', 'GHD9','GHD9','GDH11','GDH13']}
```

Transformed DF

```
data1={'Col1':[1,2,3,4,5,-1],
'Col2':[1,2,3,3,-1,-1],
'Col3':[1,2,3,-1,-1,-1],
'Col4':[1,2,3,3,4,5]}
```

the number system will be decided based on a function for ex. def weighted_value(df.geneid): return (seed). The weighted_value function will give the seed value.

Comment: Please provide a good example and show your work.

Comment: The original weighted_value function returns 3 values seed, a function and fill value. for simplicity of asking I made it as one value. My approach is a manual construction of data by for looping and when ready convert it to a data frame.  1st find the # of unique values 1st df.col call; then call the weighted function; use it to create a data string; store it in a dict with key as col name and data as the string. repeat for all cols. I have 100+  columns. It is nothing but a string manipulation. The other approach i was thinking was to use SQL procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass you data into dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
newdf=df.apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0]+1).where(df!='',-1)
newdf
Out[12]: 
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     1     1     1     1
1     2     2     2     2
2     3     3     3     3
3     4     3    -1     3
4     5    -1    -1     4
5    -1    -1    -1     5
```

Then using `to_dict`

```
newdf.to_dict('l')
Out[19]: 
{'Col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1],
 'Col2': [1, 2, 3, 3, -1, -1],
 'Col3': [1, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1],
 'Col4': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]}
```